# Is it possible to have async methods as callbacks to eventhandlers in c#?

Tags: c#, async-await

My design is illustrated by below example. Having a while true loop doing something and notifying by an event that it has done something to all subscribers. My application should not continue its execution before its done notifying all subscribers, where this works as long as someone do not put a async void on the callback.

If someone put a async void on the callback to await some task, then my loop can continue before the callback is completed. What other designs can I do to avoid this situation.

Its 3th party plugins that register themeself and subscribe to the event, so I have no control over if they put a async void. Understandable I cant do Task callbacks for the EventHandler, so what alternatives do I have with .net 4.5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Test
    {

        public event EventHandler Event;

        public void DoneSomething()
        {
            if (Event != null)
                Event(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();

            test.Event += test_Event;
            test.Event +=test_Event2;

            while(true)
            {
                test.DoneSomething();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
        }

        private static void test_Event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("delegate 2");
        }

        static async void test_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Del1gate 1");

            await Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("5000 ms later");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers are really good below. I will mark the one with the most votes for the answer! I would mark them both as they both helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If someone put a async void on the callback to await some task, then my loop can continue before the callback is completed. What other designs can I do to avoid this situation.

There is really no way to avoid this.  Even if you were to somehow "know" that the subscriber wasn't implemented via `async`/`await`, you still couldn't guarantee that the caller didn't build some form of asynchronous "operation" in place.

For example, a completely normal void method could put all of its work into a `Task.Run` call.

> My application should not continue its execution before its done notifying all subscribers

Your current version *does* follow this contract.  You're notifying the subscribers synchronously - if a subscriber does something asynchronously in response to that notification, that is something outside of your control.

---

> Understandable I cant do Task callbacks for the EventHandler, so what alternatives do I have with .net 4.5.

Note that this is actually possible.  For example, you can rewrite your above as:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var test = new Test();

        test.Event += test_Event;
        test.Event +=test_Event2;

        test.DoneSomethingAsync().Wait();
    }
}

public delegate Task CustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);

private static Task test_Event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("delegate 2");
    return Task.FromResult(false);
}

static async Task test_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Del1gate 1");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("5000 ms later");
}

public class Test
{
    public event CustomEvent Event;
    public async Task DoneSomethingAsync()
    {
        var handler = this.Event;
        if (handler != null)
        {
              var tasks = handler.GetInvocationList().Cast<CustomEvent>().Select(s => s(this, EventArgs.Empty));
              await Task.WhenAll(tasks);                
        }
    }
}
```

You can also rewrite this using event add/remove, as suggested by [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick):

```
public class Test
{
    private List<CustomEvent> events = new List<CustomEvent>();
    public event CustomEvent Event
    {
        add { lock(events) events.Add(value); }
        remove { lock(events) events.Remove(value); }
    }

    public async Task DoneSomething()
    {
        List<CustomEvent> handlers;
        lock(events) 
            handlers = this.events.ToList(); // Cache this
        var tasks = handlers.Select(s => s(this, EventArgs.Empty));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether it would make more sense to have custom `add` and `remove`, rather than using `GetInvocationList()`, especially since that could be completely type-safe.

Comment: @svick Something like the above?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the ideas :) Thats exactly what I was after. Would it make sense, and how, to extend this such a subscriber could add both void methods and task methods. Possible using BeginInvoke and GetInvocationList. Guess I will try play alittle around with that myself. Thanks again.

Comment: @s093294 Not as an event - an event needs to have a fixed signature for the delegate.  You could use 2 events (one for each) and let people subscribe to either, but as soon as you allow void returning methods, you have your initial issue.

Comment: I think that both answers here gave me a way better overview over my design options. I will also put my faith into developers will learn over time to think twice when doing a async void :)

Answer (score 3):

> My application should not continue its execution before its done notifying all subscribers, where this works as long as someone do not put a async void on the callback.

I have a blog entry on [designing for `async` event handlers](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html). It is possible to use `Task`-returning delegates or to wrap an existing `SynchronizationContext` within your own (which would allow you to detect and wait for `async void` handlers).

However, I recommend you use "deferrals", which are objects designed specifically to solve this problem for Windows Store applications. A simple `DeferralManager` is available in my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DeferralManager&referringTitle=Documentation).

Your event args can define a `GetDeferral` method as such:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  private readonly DeferralManager deferrals = new DeferralManager();

  ... // Your own constructors and properties.

  public IDisposable GetDeferral()
  {
    return deferrals.GetDeferral();
  }

  internal Task WaitForDeferralsAsync()
  {
    return deferrals.SignalAndWaitAsync();
  }
}
```

And you can raise an event and (asynchronously) wait for all asynchronous handlers to complete like this:

```
private Task RaiseMyEventAsync()
{
  var handler = MyEvent;
  if (handler == null)
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null); // or TaskConstants.Completed

  var args = new MyEventArgs(...);
  handler(args);
  return args.WaitForDeferralsAsync();
}
```

The benefit of the "deferral" pattern is that it is well-established in the Windows Store APIs, so it's likely to be recognized by end users.

Comment: Doesn't this implementation mean that the async subscribers execute concurrently (at least if there is no synchronization context)? I'm not sure that's always desired.

Comment: If there's no synchronization context/task scheduler, then yes, the handlers may execute concurrently. I don't see this as a problem; if there *should* be a context, it would be provided by the framework. The other solutions (e.g., `Task.WhenAll`) all have the same concurrency semantics.